# self executing anonymous functions + Comma seperated statements

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

Can anyone explain the following code piece. I am aware this type of function calling is anonymous functions. But i am not sure how comma separated statements will work inside it, especially in for loop. Please point out related articles if any.

```
(function (p1, p2) {
    a = "", b = "", c = "";
    x = p2();
    y = p1("AAABBBCC");

    f1 = function() {
        return y.shift()
    }, d = "", e = "", f = "", h = !0, g = f1();
    for (i = 0; y.length && h; i++)
        a.length != 12 && (a += g, g = f1()), b.length != 11 && (b += g, g = f1())
})(1, 2)
```

The above just example, Some of it may be invalid.

-cmo

Comment: Which language are you using? Please add the appropriate tag!

Comment: This code doesn't even work.

Comment: It seems this is obfuscated code

Comment: That is nonsense code. For example, p1 is assigned a value of 1 and yet it is being used as a function. The commas in the for loop merely separate multiple assignments. The && before an assignment in parentheses make the parenthetical assignment only happen if the value of the preceding condition is true.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're asking about the Comma operator. MDN is here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator

Briefly, any two expressions can be combined into using it. This includes assignments.